# Compare two sets of dates to each other to see if one is found inside the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I have two sets of dates (4 dates total), let's call them sets A and B.  I need to see if set B date range is found in any order in set A.  Below is an example of how the dates would be found:

Set A:

```
Start          Stop
11/9/2017      11/10/2017  
11/16/2017     11/18/2017
```

Set B

```
Start          Stop
11/7/2017      11/11/2017   # should match the first one in set A
11/15/2017     11/16/2017   # Should match the second one in set A
```

I figured a set of `<` `>` 's would work, but I can't seem to get it to match what I am looking for.

I have tried the following:

```
start1 = datetime(2017,11,9)
stop2 = datetime(2017,11,10)
start2 = datetime(2017,11,7)
stop2 = datetime(2017,11,11)

start1 >= start2 or stop1 <= stop2
```

this yields true.  But i feel that i may be missing some by having the `or`, in there.

Comment: Please give a [mcve], *"can't seem to get it to match"* isn't a particularly useful description of the problem.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)?

Comment: isnt this pretty much the answer below?  it still doesnt seem to work for me though.  Though this is what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very rudimentary example of comparing dates in **Python 3**:

```
set_a_start = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)
set_a_end = datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 31)

set_b_start = datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 1)
set_b_end = datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 30)

if(set_a_start <= set_b_start and set_a_end >= set_b_end):
    print("Set B is within Set A")
```

**Update**: added "<=" for cases where both sets share the same start date (">=" for end dates)

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the `>` `<`  with dates ha.  so i have the following and it doesn't work.  but if i add `>=` to it, it does.  will this give me false positives with other combinations?  i want to say no, but with dates, there's no telling, ha

Comment: so using what you have, if i have the following dates, it says its false:
    `set_a_start = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5)`
    `set_a_end = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 6)`
    
    `set_b_start = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 3)`
    `set_b_end = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 6)`
but if i swap the start and ends around, it says true.

Comment: Yea that makes sense, because with those dates, set B is not within set A - it's actually larger than set A